# Linearized Euler-Poisson equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, plasma-physics, linearized-theory

Normalized Euler-Poisson system have the form

$$n_t+(nu)_x=0$$
$$u_t+uu_x=\phi_x$$
$$\epsilon^2\phi_xx=n-e^\phi$$

where $u $: ion velocity, $n$: the ion density and $\phi$: electrical potential, The parameter $\epsilon>0$ stands for a scaled Debey length 
this equation linearlized by

$$(I-\partial_x^2)\phi_{tt}-\phi_{xx}=0$$

from which the dispersive relation

$$w(k)=k(1+k^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

I want to know the process of linearizing.

Comment: Is the form with $\phi_{tt}$ and $\phi_{xx}$ the pre- or post-linearized form?  It's not clear about what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set

$u = u_0 + u', \phi = \phi_0 + \phi', n = n_0+n'$

where $u_0,\phi_0$ and $n_0$ are constants and quantities with primes are small quantities. Then perform a Taylor Expansion of the equations. In more precise language, small quantities are quantities, where all products with other small quantities including the quantity itself can be set to Zero. Thus you can do a Taylor Expansion to first order, all higher orders can be neglected.

For example:

$n_t+(nu)_x = (n_0+n')_t+((n_0+n')(u_0+u'))_x = n'_t + (n_0u'+n'u_0+n'u')_x = n_t' + n_0u'_x + u_0 n'_x = 0$ ($n'u' = 0$ by smallness of primed quantities).